# How can i get my datagridview code let work in a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, datagrid

I have create a win forms with a datagridview. Where i can insert update delete
articles from the database.

But i need a wpf not a win forms project. The problem is in wpf you don't have a datagridview.

Now i have try for let work it with a datagrid but there are no row options.

i have already found how i can load the data from the wcf in my datagrid with this    DgArtikel.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;

but how can i let work the insert update and delete button ?

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        ServiceReference1.Service1Client objService = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client(); // Add service reference



        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            showdata();

        }



        private void showdata()  // To show the data in the DataGridView
        {

            DataSet ds,ds2 = new DataSet();

            ds = objService.SelectUserDetails();
            ds2 = objService.SelectCombobox();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

            dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);


            ComboBoxCategorie.DataSource = ds2.Tables[0];
            ComboBoxCategorie.DisplayMember = "Categorie";


        }



        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;

            textBoxArtikel.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

            textBoxOmschrijving.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();

            textBoxVerkoopprijs.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();

            textBoxInStock.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();

            ComboBoxCategorie.SelectedValue = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ServiceReference1.UserDetails objuserdetail = new ServiceReference1.UserDetails(); // Add type reference
          //  objuserdetail.UserID = count;
            objuserdetail.Artikel = textBoxArtikel.Text;

            objuserdetail.Omschrijving = textBoxOmschrijving.Text;

            objuserdetail.Verkoopprijs =  Convert.ToInt32(textBoxVerkoopprijs.Text);

            objuserdetail.Instock = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxInStock.Text);


           objuserdetail.Cat_id = ComboBoxCategorie.SelectedIndex;
            objService.InsertUserDetails(objuserdetail); // To insert the data


            showdata();
        }

        private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ServiceReference1.UserDetails objuserdetail = new ServiceReference1.UserDetails();

            if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 1)
            {

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

             //   objuserdetail.UserID = (int)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value;

                objService.DeleteUserDetails(objuserdetail); // To Delete the data

                showdata();

            }
        }

        private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ServiceReference1.UserDetails objuserdetail = new ServiceReference1.UserDetails();

            objuserdetail.Artikel_id = (int)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value;

            objuserdetail.Artikel = textBoxArtikel.Text;

            objuserdetail.Omschrijving = textBoxOmschrijving.Text;

            objuserdetail.Verkoopprijs = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxVerkoopprijs.Text);

            objuserdetail.Instock = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxInStock.Text);

            objService.UpdateRegistrationTable(objuserdetail); // To Update the Data

            showdata();

            textBoxArtikel.Text = "";

            textBoxOmschrijving.Text = "";

            textBoxVerkoopprijs.Text = "";

            textBoxInStock.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: WPF is fundamentally different from winforms. You need to embrace XAML and Databinding instead of procedurally manipulating UI elements. Basically all your winforms code is not reusable in WPF.

Comment: Create a proper strongly typed data model instead of using magic-string based DataTable stuff, and then use DataBinding to show that data in the UI.